# Spoonerism for words?

Tags: single-word-requests

So, for those who don't know a *Spoonerism* (or at least one definition) is a transposition of the first letters of words (often with comic results). Some examples:

- "Go and shake a tower." (Go and take a shower.)
- "Queer, old dean." (Dear, old Queen).
- "Po narking." (No parking.)

I would like to know the word to describe a similar incident involving whole words:

- "Teeth your brush" (brush your teeth.)
- "Guitar your practice" (practice your guitar.)

Personally, I have most often noticed this to be a case of swapping the verb with the direct object.

---

In order to conform with the standards of the [single-word-requests](/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) tag, a potential sentence:

> It is unclear whether his tendency to *<swap predicate and object>* was caused by a bizarre sense of humor or a freak accident involving a cantaloupe to the head.

Comment: **[Transposition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/transpose)** might work, although you might want to qualify it by saying "*lexical transposition*" or the like to specify your intention.

Comment: [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) has a command, `dissociated-press`, that scrambles text word by word or character by character. You tell it how many words or characters to overlap.

Comment: The examples provided are both imperative sentences that can be described as simple reversals of normal word order.  If the phenomenon you are attempting to name would also apply to indicative and interrogative sentences, examples of those would be useful.

Comment: I always liked this one: "Go, and know more sin." (Go, and sin no more.)

Comment: My favorite spoonerism:
"He's a feet sweller." (He's a sweet feller.)

Comment: And a recent one, of meme popularity: “I'm not as think as you stoned I am!”

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be angling at the idea that this transposition is accidental, not intentional.  In that case, you might take a look at [synchysis](http://humanities.byu.edu/rhetoric/Figures/S/synchysis.htm), which is an inversion of word order not being done for emphasis.

A generic term for using words out of normal order is [hyperbaton](http://humanities.byu.edu/rhetoric/Figures/H/hyperbaton.htm), but that includes all sorts of softer transpositions like "life aquatic" and Yoda-speak like "Gone to the dark side, he has."

Comment: My upvote for quoting Yoda this has.